# material desing Textfield dropdown how to implement

Tags: android

I need to implement this component in my app:

[image: Material Design component]

Just to reinforce that, what I need is a drop down in the text field, not a drop down in action bar.

In the material design components guidelines, this component is known as a [text-field (or exposed) dropdown](https://material.io/components/menus#exposed-dropdown-menu). Are there any ways to implement this component?

Comment: Hi Aleskey, i don't thing that it's the same, but thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spPaymentType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

Comment: Hi J Whitfield, right now i'm in office and can't test this right now, but when i get home, i will try and I let you know.

Comment: it's works, thank you so much. i cant mark your anwser as the correct, but probably some one will do that.

Comment: I doubt it as you asked the question but I'm glad it help you.

Comment: textfield has a hint (label) which is visible when there is a text in the field, [see here](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B5ZSepuCX1xOclNKT1VtQ0FnMVk/dropdown.png) which is missing in this case.this label changes color when the field is selected. do you know how to show that too?